# Python LIME keep returning nonsense errors Index out of bounds or input feature length not match

Tags: python, random-forest, feature-selection, lime

In python A randomforestregressor of y onto 16 numeric features (variables).

Now I have an array of length 16, which is correct, because I have 16 features
[image]
But I got an error:
[image]

I don't know what is going on.

I even tried to input an array with the test value (so array of 17 values)
But now it said input feature length should be 16. IT WAS 16!!!!!!!
[image]